# Parse.com - differencies between query.find( ) and query.findinBackground( )

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my project I use only the function `query.find()` in `Asynctask` to manage my data, for example:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String tipo,data;
        int stato;

        ParseObject object = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Status",id);
        query= ParseQuery.getQuery("Documenti");
        query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.whereEqualTo("documentgenerated",object);

        try
        {
            results = query.find();
            counter = results.size();

            if(counter != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<results.size(); i++)
                {
                 date = results.get(i).getCreatedAt();
                 tipo = results.get(i).getString("topologia");
                 stato = results.get(i).getInt("stato");


                        ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) results.get(i).get("file");
                        uri= Uri.parse(fileObject.getUrl());
                        card.add(new DocumentType(data,certificate,uri));


                }

            }
```

and it works well. But I know that there is also this function:

```
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

                        }
                    });



        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

I want to ask you if there is a difference between `query.find()` in `Asynctask` and `findInBackground()` function or these functions do the same works in background (expecially if `findInBackground()` works as a `Service`).

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findInBackground()` is executed in new background thread (is not a service is just a thread), since you already are in background thread is no need to call `findInBackground()` except if you have some specific requirements and you need multiple threads...

So you can use `findInBackground()` from main thread and remove asynTask or you use `find()` inside asyTask if you have additional preprocessing or post processing that you must execute in background thread